# Requesting debug_info in an Erlang module using -compile

Tags: debugging, erlang, compiler-directives

I want to force the Erlang compiler to generate debug info for specific modules whenever I compile them, without having to add the `debug_info` argument to the compilation command.  I tried adding

```
-compile([debug_info]).
```

to the module file, but running `c(my_module)` did not include the debug info in the beam file.

Is there a way to do this, or debug information can not be added from the module source file itself?

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916305/debugging-symbols-in-erlang

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-compile` directive without the enclosing list around the option:

```
-compile(debug_info).
```

Comment: You're right. Seems that the compile option is given (as seen when calling `Module:module_info()`) but not used. Other compile options do work (such as `export_all`). I'd report this as a bug on the [erlang-bugs mailing list](http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-bugs).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, even if it's a bit unconvenient. From the shell:

`compile:file(my_module.erl, debug_info)`

or

`c(my_module.erl, debug_info)`